# Why this simple reference to figures does not work as expected?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm trying to reference two figures, but somehow the tagging mechanisms is not working properly. I have done this thousand of times, and it's driving me crazy. I have come to the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Section name}

Reference to Fig. \ref{fig:1}.

Reference to Fig. \ref{fig:2}.


\begin{figure}
  \label{fig:1}
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{5cm}
  \caption{xx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \label{fig:2}
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{5cm}
  \caption{xx}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

And the output I get looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: Because the `\label` command if before the `\caption`. You have to put the `\label` *always after* the `\caption`.

Comment: Additionally, it is not the `figure` env that provides the number (in contrast to for example a theorem env), it comes from `\caption` and **have** to go **after** caption in order to pick up the number

Comment: OK I see how it works, as well as the duplicated threat, which I didn't find when posting. Thanks for the fast and accurate hints.